# GameObject shaped like a piece of cake in Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unityscript, blender, unity-game-engine

sorry for my bad english. I'm from germany^^

My question:

Is it possible to transform an empty game object into a shape that Looks
like a Piece of cake? I have a round terrain and I want to "cut" it in
three pieces of cake, because I want to play different music in all three areas. I Need These pieces of cake as a box/mesh collider or something like this, so I can Play different Songs if the Player collides with the box/mesh collider.

Ideas anyone? Please help me. :)
Is it possible to build an object in Blender for example and use it
as an invisible box collider?

Comment: Franz .. the answer is simple, ***no, not inside Unity***.  You must have your model-making department do it, or, make the model yourself using Autodesk, Maya, etc.  If you are Mac, get Cheetah3D (an excellent product from .de !!)  mfg, JB

Comment: note!  in a pinch, you can **somewhat fake it** by just sitting three thin rectangle colliders together.  get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the shape in Blender. Create a MESH COLLIDER. Assign your piece of cake model to the MESH parameter of the MESH collider. Scale it. Position it. set it as trigger and VOILA!

This would be the mesh you create in blender (RED)
[image]

then,

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    //play song
}
```

Comment: Quite right.  Again, if you have a Mac, get **Cheetah3D**. Blender is crap.

Comment: Blender is one of the best 3D tools on market and it is free. I know what I am talking as I was 3D artist using 3ds max, maya and many smaller packages. If you say it is crap please tell why :D

Comment: because it's free Jerry !

Comment: @JoeBlow That's not very good advice :/ Free tools can be great.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have covered options of generating a mesh outside of Unity and using it to make a mesh collider trigger for your music changes.

Other options:

1. Native Unity collider option:

Use two native cube mesh colliders to create a sandwich of two thin colliders at the borders where the music needs to change.  Do some [OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)/[OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) scripting to make the music change correctly when the player crosses the borders.

2. Pure scripting option:

Use the player position relative to the "center of the cake" point to calculate when to change the music based on where the player is located.